# Why are all the CCSM tick-boxes grayed out?

Tags: 12.04, compiz

I was editing my desktop and while editing it everything got hidden like top panel and left side panel. I restored it and it worked properly but i cant click on any tick button on the icons given on CompizConfig Settings Manager. I dont even have an option to click or edit it. Please help me out as soon as possible. I even tried reinstalling `compiz`, and purging it.

This screenshot shows the problem ([click here to show it bigger](http://oi48.tinypic.com/jkbswz.jpg)):

[image: Screenshot showing CCSM with unclickable checkboxes.]

I cannot click on any tick button (i.e., any checkbox) near all these icons, while I can open and edit all these icons.

Comment: Please try `unity --reset`; did you log in to Ubuntu 2D by mistake?

Comment: i tried unitu reset but it just resets what i lost on my desktop.

Comment: and i dont know if i entered 2D by mistake, if it is so, how to recover it?.

Answer (score 0):

To get back to unity 3d just log out then click the little icon next to your name an choose Ubuntu.

Comment: i did the same thing sir but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: please someone help i am still stucked in that.

Answer (score 0):

You said you reinstalled `compiz` and that you purged it. Does that mean it's installed now, or not?

Just in case something went wrong (and this will potentially help with some other possible problems too), try logging in to a Unity 2D session (select Ubuntu 2D on the login screen), running `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install compiz ccsm`, and rebooting.

Then select Ubuntu (not Ubuntu 2D) as your session type, and see if the problem is fixed (or in any way changed).

This won't necessarily help but it is, at the least, an important diagnostic step, to try before attempting other ideas.

*I'm posting this as community-wiki because it's not really that different from other ideas here, and because I want to make it as easy as possible for people to expand this to add other troubleshooting steps for this specific CCSM problem ...if they feel like doing so. Of course, separate answers should still be posted...as separate answers.*